# Update Progress not seen

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updateprogress

I have a utility which uploads a file and then process it and saves it. So I have a file upload control, a btn to upload and a cancel btn with couple of labels to display messages.

Problem: I cant see the update progress when I hit btnupload or btncancel. 
Here is the code.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblerrormsg" runat="server" class="lblerrormsg"></asp:Label>
</ContentTemplate> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:Label ID="lblsource" runat="server" class="lblleft" Text="Select file ">   
</asp:Label>
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadSource" runat="server" class="BtnUpload" />
<asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" class="btnRefresh"    
OnClientClick="ClearFileUpload()"                                                   
CssClass="btnRefresh" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="btnUnlock" runat="server" Text="Process File"       
class="btnRefresh" OnClick="btnUnlock_Click"  CssClass="btnRefresh" /> 
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" DisplayAfter="100" 
AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel2" >
<ProgressTemplate>
<img alt="Loading" src="Images/updateprogress.gif"   />
</ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
<asp:Label ID="lblSaved" runat="server" class="lblleft"></asp:Label><br/>
<asp:Label ID="lblsourcePath" runat="server" class="lblleft"></asp:Label>
</ContentTemplate> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblerrormsg" runat="server" class="lblerrormsg"></asp:Label>
</ContentTemplate> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>`
```

Please help.
Thanks 
Chand

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate AssociatedUpdatePanelID and try since it's inside the UpdatePanel I don't think you need it.

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is because an asp.net file upload is not an asynchronous event and asp.net Ajax gets blocked whilst the upload is in progress.

The only way i've solved this in the past is to write my own uploader that sends the file through an iframe, and a custom handler on the server that reflects the posted file out of the underlying http request so you can save it as a stream whilst alerting the client of it's progress.

The reason for that is any attempt to read the request normally causes the whole file to be loaded into memory.

Comment: Can you post your custom code ? Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: in a related note:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321171/fileupload-with-updateprogress

Comment: Sadly, I can't directly as it's part of a control that my employer 'owns'; but I can link to a Code project article that is quite ... informative ;)   http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/UpldFileToDiskProgressBar.aspx

Comment: You're welcome; sorry I can't commit my actual code but let me know if you try to follow this article and hit any snags.  The principle is truly straight forward but make sure to download the sample project to get the Javascript bit you'll need.

Answer (score 0):

The Button and the UpdateProgress controls both need to be in an update panel, or you need to take the UpdateProgress control out of the UpdatePanel.

Comment: If I put the button in update panel, the File upload dont work.

Comment: Put the file upload in there too, along with any other controls that you want to be AJAX driven. I don't know if the file upload will work with AJAX though.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't; The Panel will render the upload and will let it function but you won't get asynchronous behavior.